# Arrange plot in order based on custom user input ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am taking a custom user input and trying to plot a bar graph in shiny. Is there a way to reorder the graph based on custom user input? Here is the code:

```
ggplot(head(initial_data_ip_analysis, 10), aes(reorder(ip_address, -opex), opex)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",  fill="steelblue",
                                                                            color="black", position=position_dodge()) +  
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + 
geom_text(aes(label=opex), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.25, size = 3) + xlab("ip_address")
```

In the code `ip_address` and `opex` are specific columns in the df, I want the `ip_address` to be a custom user input. So instead of hardcoded `ip_address` it could be anything like `ip_location` or `ip_domain` but at the same time `opex` stays constant since it will be fixed in my case. Sample plot:[image]

Comment: look at `aes_string`

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` so folks can work with

Comment: Let me gather some sample data. Sorry about that. @GordonShumway I had tried aes_string but the problem is it works fine without the reorder. I will update my the error I get when I replace aes with aes_string. sampler: `opex not defined` even though I had set `opex <- "opex"` before hand.